# $(A\in B: \int_A f d\lambda=0)$ where f satisfies: $\forall t \in R: \int_{-\infty}^t f =0 d\lambda$ is Dynkin-System

Tags: real-analysis

I have to show the following:

Let $f:R\to R, f\in L^1(R,\lambda)$

$D=(A\in B(R): \int_A f d\lambda=0)$ where f satisfies: $\forall t \in R: \int_{-\infty}^t f =0 d\lambda$ is Dynkin-System. Then show that f=0 a.e.

---

My ideas:

first I show the Dynkin-System:

1. As $f\in L^1$ daoe this imply that $\lim_{t\to\infty} \int_{-\infty}^t f =\int_{-\infty}^\infty f=0 $. Because the i would get $R \in D$
2. Let $A\in D \Rightarrow  \int_A f d\lambda =0$  and as $R\in D$ I get:  $\int_{A^c} f d\lambda=\int_{R} f d\lambda-\int_{A} f d\lambda= 0-0=0 $ and therefore $A^c \in D$
3. Let $A_n \in D$ be pairwise disjunct sets: $\int_{A_1\cup A_2} f d\lambda =\int_{A_1} f d\lambda +\int_{A_2} f d\lambda= 0+0=0 $ and by induction i get it $\cup_{n \in N} A_n \in D$

is this up to this step correct? And is in 1) the argument with $f\in L^1 $ also correct?

$f=0$ a.e. i would argue that in $B(R)$ every intervall can be written as intersections and complements of intervalls of the form $(-\infty,t]$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) and 2) your argument is fine. You cannot use indeuction for 3). But it is a well known fact that $\int_A fd\lambda =\sum_n \int_{A_n} fd\lambda $ of $f$ is integrable and $A$ is the disjoint union of $A_1,A_2,...$.

To show that $f=0$ a.e. you have to apply Dynkin system's Theorem. You need a $\pi$ system contained in $D$. Note that $\int_a^{b} fd\lambda=\int_{-\infty}^{b} fd\lambda-\int_{-\infty}^{b} fd\lambda=0$. Intervals of the form $(a,b)$ form a $\pi-$system genearting the Borel $\sigma-$ algebra. Hence, $\int_A fd\lambda=0$ for every Borel set $A$, which implies $f=0$ a.e.